# How should I pass data from my service to snack bar component?

Tags: angular-material, angular6, angular2-services, subject, snackbar

I have a snackbar component which I have created like this!

```
import {Component, ViewEncapsulation, OnInit, OnDestroy} from '@angular/core';
import {
  MatSnackBar,
  MatSnackBarConfig,
  MatSnackBarHorizontalPosition,
  MatSnackBarVerticalPosition,
} from '@angular/material';
import { Subscription } from 'rxjs';


import { AuthenticationService } from "../../services/authentication.service";


@Component({
  selector: 'snack-message',
  templateUrl: './messages.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './mesaages.component.scss' ],
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None
})

export class SnackBarMessages implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
  action: boolean = true;
  setAutoHide: boolean = true;
  autoHide: number = 2000;
  horizontalPosition: MatSnackBarHorizontalPosition = 'center';
  verticalPosition: MatSnackBarVerticalPosition = 'bottom';
  private showMessageSub: Subscription;
  messageData: object;

  addExtraClass: boolean = false;

constructor(public snackBar: MatSnackBar, public authenticationService: AuthenticationService) {

}

ngOnInit() {
  this.messageData = this.authenticationService.getMessageData();
  this.showMessageSub = this.authenticationService.getMessageListener()
      .subscribe(data => {
          this.messageData = data;
      });
   this.openMessageSnackBar(this.messageData);
}

 openMessageSnackBar(data) {
  let config = new MatSnackBarConfig();
  config.verticalPosition = this.verticalPosition;
  config.horizontalPosition = this.horizontalPosition;
  config.duration = this.setAutoHide ? this.autoHide : 0;
  this.snackBar.open(data.message, data.action, config);
 }

 ngOnDestroy() {
   if (this.showMessageSub) {
     this.showMessageSub.unsubscribe();
   }
 }
}
```

> I have added subject and i have created a subscription which listens to the messageListener in my Authentication Service. Then i call next with my subjectListener with the data I want to pass. I am not getting any call on my component. I don't understand why ? This is my Service!

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Subject } from 'rxjs';
import { Router, ActivatedRoute } from '../../../node_modules/@angular/router';
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})

export class AuthenticationService {
  private mesageListener = new Subject<object>();
  private messageData: object;

getMessageListener() {
    return this.mesageListener.asObservable();
  }

getMessageData() {
    return this.messageData;
  }


createUser(email: string, password: string) {
    const userData: AuthModel = { 
      email: email,
      password: password
    }
    const requestPath = this.getModes()[`${this.navigatedFrom}`];
    this.http.post(`http://localhost:3000/api/${requestPath}/signup`,userData)
      .subscribe(response => {
        this.messageData = {
          message: 'Sign Up Successful. Please Login now!',
          action: 'Ok! Got it.'
        }
        this.mesageListener.next(this.messageData);
      });
  }

}
```

Comment: Can anyone help me on this!! So dying to have it's solution!!

Comment: when is the createUser()-method called?

Comment: Its called from another component which creates user and then I want send Signed Up info to user through snackbar!

Comment: you need to inject the HttpClient: constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

Comment: Sorry Dirk, I have removed the constructor so that the focus is only on the code i am writing for snackbar. The crux is that every thing is working except for the observable call in component.  The .next method on listener is called in authentication service but am not getting any call or update on the snackbar component.

Comment: Are Subjects and subscription only meant only for string, boolean and Arrays, can i really pass object through subject and subscription.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use `new BehaviorSubject<object>(null);` for mesageListener .

you can see more details on Subject and BehavoiurSubject here : [angular2-difference-between-a-behavior-subject-and-an-observable/](https://hassantariqblog.wordpress.com/2016/12/03/angular2-difference-between-a-behavior-subject-and-an-observable/)

In Component subscribe to the value of Observable. It should work.